# three.js create texture from cubecamera

Tags: three.js

When using a cube camera one normally sets the envMap of the material to the cubeCamera.renderTarget, e.g.:

```
var myMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff, 
        envMap: myCubeCamera.renderTarget,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide});
```

This works great for meshes that are meant to reflect or refract what the cube camera sees. However, I'd like to simply create a texture and apply that to my mesh. In other words, I don't want my object to reflect or refract. I want the face normals to be ignored.

I tried using a THREE.WebGLRenderTarget, but it won't handle a cube camera. And using a single perpspective camera with WebGLRenderTarget does not give me a 360 texture, obviously.

Finally, simply assigning the cubeCamera.renderTarget to the 'map' property of the material doesn't work either.

Is it possible to do what I want?

r73.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Set the refractionRatio on the material to 1.0. Then face normals are ignored since no refraction is occurring.

In a normal situation where the Cube Camera is in the same scene as the mesh, this would be pointless because the mesh would be invisible. But in cases where the Cube Camera is looking at a different scene, then this is a useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: this is not what the author of the question is looking for, I'll keep my answer below for other people**

Your envmap is already a texture so there's no need to apply it as a map. Also, cubemaps and textures are structurally different, so it won't be possible to swap them, or if you succeed in doing that the result is not what you probably you might expect.

I understand from what you're asking you want a static envmap instead to be updated at each frame, if that's the case simply don't run `myCubeCamera.updateCubeMap()` into your render function. Instead place it at the end of your scene initialization with your desired cube camera position, your envmap will show only that frame.

See examples below:

- [Dynamic Cubemap Example](http://codepen.io/luigimannoni/pen/fdpLC)
- [Static Cubemap Example](http://codepen.io/luigimannoni/pen/jWVjYb)

Comment: I don't want a static envmap. I want a texture that is updated on each frame. I just want a texture not a reflection or a refraction. I want the face normals to be ignore. Is there any way to extract a texture from my cubeCamera?

Comment: Hmm, I still don't get what are you trying to achieve here, are you trying to convert a [cubic map to an equirectangular image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504584/cubic-to-equirectangular-projection-algorithm)? If it's the case I can definitely tell you the cubecamera are simply 6 cameras with a `WebGLRenderTarget` call on each of those, you could try to build your own so you have more granular control for each face and you could extract the sides manually and then rearrange them on a plane/face. If that's not the thing you're after I'll pass the ball to someone else.